# Android SSL certificates. Failing to connect to aws elb. SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname <ELB_API_ENDPOINT> not verified:

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, retrofit2

Im halfway through building an app but am struggling to securely connect to my dotnet api running on an aws ec2 instance behind a elastic load balancer. The load balancer routes all http traffic to an https listener which checks for a list of ssl certificates registered on aws acm. At the moment im getting this error. Im using retrofit2 for the request on the android side

```
SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname <ELB_API_ENDPOINT> not verified:

certificate: sha256/gvQ6PWTz+S+fSwvqCQ/UBxcnQVj5ebsBM4xhW+9wuv0=

DN: CN=<HOSTNAME OF MY WEBSITE WHICH ALSO CONNECTS TO THE ELB>

subjectAltNames: [<HOSTNAME OF MY WEBSITE WHICH ALSO CONNECTS TO THE ELB>]
```

Any knowledge on these would help me out a ton - in a bit of a rut <3

What is best practice for storing ssl keys on android applications?

To create a cert (using certbot) you need a hostname, what are hostnames in the context of android apps (as opposed to hostnames on webapps)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have your own domain? How did you set up your ssl cert?

Comment: yes i have my own domains that i use for websites - setup through aws acm, however aws does not let you download the keys for those certs so they can only be used with aws resources. Should i buy a new domain and set up a cert through certbot soley for my android app?

Comment: You can import your own keys to acm and use that on the alb.

Comment: Yeah i get that part, should i use a new domain (purely for the app) when creating the cert? and where should i store that cert on the android app? cheers